# Why does StreamingContext.socketTextStream give "ERROR scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Why does the following code fail?

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

val lStream = ssc.socketTextStream("127.0.0.1", 7777)

val words = lStream.flatMap(x => x.split(" ")).countByValue()

words.print()

ssc.start()
```

Getting below error

```
17/07/27 17:34:08 ERROR scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms:
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:7777 - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused                                              
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)                                                               
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)                                        
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)                                 
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)                                          
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)                                                          
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)                                                                            
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)                                                                            
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)                                                                             
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)                                                                             
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.SocketReceiver.receive(SocketInputDStream.scala:73)                              
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.SocketReceiver$$anon$2.run(SocketInputDStream.scala:59)
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is because no application listens to `7777` port on `127.0.0.1`.

You could use [nc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) utility to have one, but that's merely for demo purposes. Start one session using the following command (choose one per operating system you use).

```
// OpenBSD / macOS
nc -lk 7777

// other OSes
nc -lk -p 7777
```

Refer to [A Quick Example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#a-quick-example) in Spark's documentation.